# How can I execute a program (C/C++) after uploading it to Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I've written a number of C/C++ programs in my local environment that I pushed to Bluemix using  `cf push MYAPP`  with null-buildpack-master for the buildpack.

Now I want to execute those programs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to specify two pieces of information to my `cf push` command to do this.

First use the `-c` option with the command to start my program.
Second use the `-b` option with a null-buildpack to indicate no actual buildpack is required to run the comand.

For example:

`cf push -c ./RunMeNow -b https://github.com/ryandotsmith/null-buildpack`